# Binding to a property in ControlTemplate does not work

Tags: xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I have a mobile app with Xamarin.Forms and FreshMvvm. Every page uses a control template defined in App.xaml:

```
          <ControlTemplate x:Key="MainPageTemplate">
            <Grid BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="9*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{local:ImageResource MyApp.Images.My_logo.jpg}" Margin="0, 0, 0, 5" Grid.Row="0" />
                <Label Text="{Binding ScreenName}" FontSize="Subtitle" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1" />
                <Label Text="{Binding ErrorMessage}" TextColor="Red" Grid.Row="2" />
                <ContentPresenter Margin="10, 0, 10, 10" Grid.Row="3" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

The ScreenName property is defined in the PageModel like this:

```
        protected string _screenName;

        public string ScreenName => _screenName;
```

For some reason, the ScreenName is not showing up on the page that uses the control template. It does if I replace the Binding with a hard-coded text:

```
<Label Text="Something" ...
```

Comment: Unless that property is getting set in the constructor of your view model, you will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and let the UI know the property has updated.

Comment: @TaylorD Thank you for your comment. I did initialize the property in the constructor, but it did not help...

Comment: Next thought is that you're setting your binding context to your page and not your ViewModel, so try to bind to `BindingContext.ScreenName` instead.

Comment: @TaylorD Yes! That was it! Could you please make it your Answer, and I will mark it as such. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting your `BindingContext` to your `{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`, your binding context is the page.

To access your ViewModel, you must change your xaml to access your property through the "BindingContext" of your page.

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding BindingContext.ScreenName}" FontSize="Subtitle" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help!